# I have connected to Firebase-remote-config. Do I need to provide a test account to the reviewer?

Tags: android, firebase-remote-config

I use Firbase RemoteConfig to remotely configure a parameter for my application, and dynamically adjust the background color within the application through the parameter. Do I need to provide a test account to the reviewers for functional testing during the review?

Looking forward to answer